# How do I define a private static final field using ByteBuddy with an initial complex value?

Tags: byte-buddy

After reading the documentation and a [few Github issues](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/227#issuecomment-264884960), which proved to be particularly useful, I came to understand that in ByteBuddy terminology a `static` field must be set to its initial value by a `LoadedTypeInitializer` of some kind.

I didn't know what to do with a `LoadedTypeInitializer.ForStaticField` once I had created it.  Then, thankfully, I just happened to stumble across the `initializer()` method of `DynamicType.Builder`.  Here is my recipe (which does not work):

```
builder = builder
  .initializer(new LoadedTypeInitializer.ForStaticField("$frob", this.frob))
  .defineField("$frob",
               Frob.class,
               Ownership.STATIC,
               SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC,
               Visibility.PRIVATE,
               FieldManifestation.FINAL);
```

If I examine the value of this field via reflection after loading the type, the field is there but it is set to `null`.

If I remove `FieldManifestation.FINAL` from this recipe, it works.  But ideally I'd like my field to be `final`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The default initializer requires a non-final field but you can implement it yourself to set the value for a final field by calling `setAccessible` to `true`.

A more elegant solution might be to set the field in a static initializer. The problem with this approach that you can only set values that you assemble from compile-time constants (primitives and strings) unless you can access the field from somewhere when the initializer is invoked. As for example:

```
builder = builder.invokeable(isTypeInitializer()).intercept(MethodCall.invoke(...).setsField(...))
```

You would need to create a `FieldDescription.Latent` to reference the field you have created.

Comment: Interesting; could you expand the `...` a little more?  I understand that `setsField(...)` would accept the `FieldDescription.Latent` object.  What would the `MethodCall.invoke(...)` accept?

Comment: I wonder if I could do `builder.invokeable(isTypeInitializer()).intercept(MethodCall.callable(() -> this.frob)).setsField(latentFieldDescription)` (I've eliminated the `try`/`catch` around the `Callable` lambda for brevity).

Comment: This won't work, unfortunately since the callable is set as a value in a synthetic field. You'd need to create an actual class with a method for this.

Comment: On the other approach: sadly, simply calling `setAccessible(true)` does not "remove" the `final` modifier (for that you have to work on the `Field` class' members themselves).  This is rapidly becoming not worth the effort; it's a `private` field anyway so I'll just leave it as non-`final`.