# Can I create a ByteBuddy instrumented type with a private static final MethodHandle field in it?

Tags: byte-buddy

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219512/how-do-i-define-a-private-static-final-field-using-bytebuddy-with-an-initial-com) in the past but could not make it work (it was not clear if it was possible).

Now I find myself in a situation where I *need* to make a `private static final` field whose type (in my case) is `MethodHandle`.

In Java, of course, I could simply do:

```
private static final MethodHandle mh = goGetMethodHandle();
```

…where `goGetMethodHandle()` is a `static` function that returns the `MethodHandle` I need.

Or, equivalently, I could do:

```
private static final MethodHandle mh;
static {
  mh = goGetMethodHandle();
}
```

I am not sure what the ByteBuddy recipe should be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be accomplished more easily using the DSL:

```
builder
  .defineField("gorp", MethodHandle.class, 
     Visibility.PRIVATE, Ownership.STATIC, SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC, FieldManifestation.FINAL)
  .invokeable(isTypeInitializer())
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Some.class.getMethod("goGetMethodHandle")
    .setsField(named("gorp")))
```

Comment: Oh; I was under the impression from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244544/208288 that a latent field description was required for `private static final` fields.

Comment: It used to but a lot has happened in four years so this is a preferable option.

Comment: Great; thanks; the latent advice was from you in April of this year.  Nevertheless, I agree your recipe above is easier; thanks again. If I wanted to avoid reflection entirely, I assume the latent version is still the way to go? Just trying to understand.

Comment: April 2016, isn't it?

Comment: No; maybe StackOverflow is behaving weirdly for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61244544/208288 shows you answered on April 16, 2020.  Anyway I know you are very active on StackOverflow so it would be easy to miss/forget. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, mobile version does not show the date. I would need to dig but I added the matcher after being dissatisfied with the convenience of the mentioned common case. Thought is was a couple years back...

Comment: I guess it's been a long year! :-D

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it scares me to death:

```java
  // Excerpt from JUnit Jupiter unit test whose class is named
  // TestPrivateStaticFinalFieldInitialization:

  @Test
  final void testAll() throws Throwable {

    final MethodDescription findStaticMethodDescription = new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(MethodHandles.Lookup.class)
      .getDeclaredMethods()
      .filter(ElementMatchers.named("findStatic"))
      .getOnly();
    
    final MethodDescription methodHandlesLookupMethodDescription = new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(MethodHandles.class)
      .getDeclaredMethods()
      .filter(ElementMatchers.named("lookup"))
      .getOnly();

    final MethodDescription methodTypeMethodTypeMethodDescription = new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(MethodType.class)
      .getDeclaredMethods()
      .filter(ElementMatchers.named("methodType")
              .and(ElementMatchers.isStatic()
                   .and(ElementMatchers.takesArguments(Class.class))))
      .getOnly();
    
    final ByteBuddy byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy();
    DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = byteBuddy.subclass(Object.class);
    builder = builder
      .defineField("gorp", MethodHandle.class, Visibility.PRIVATE, Ownership.STATIC, SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC, FieldManifestation.FINAL)
      .invokable(ElementMatchers.isTypeInitializer())
      .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(findStaticMethodDescription)
                 .onMethodCall(MethodCall.invoke(methodHandlesLookupMethodDescription))
                 .with(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(TestPrivateStaticFinalFieldInitialization.class))
                 .with("goop")
                 .withMethodCall(MethodCall.invoke(methodTypeMethodTypeMethodDescription)
                                 .with(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(void.class)))
                 .setsField(new FieldDescription.Latent(builder.toTypeDescription(),
                                                        "gorp",
                                                        ModifierContributor.Resolver.of(Visibility.PRIVATE,
                                                                                        Ownership.STATIC,
                                                                                        SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC,
                                                                                        FieldManifestation.FINAL).resolve(),
                                                        TypeDescription.Generic.OfNonGenericType.ForLoadedType.of(MethodHandle.class),
                                                        Collections.emptyList())));
    final Class<?> newClass = builder.make().load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getLoaded();
    final Field gorpField = newClass.getDeclaredField("gorp");
    gorpField.setAccessible(true);
    final MethodHandle methodHandle = (MethodHandle)gorpField.get(null);
    assertNotNull(methodHandle);
    methodHandle.invokeExact();
  }

  public static final void goop() {
    System.out.println("*** goop");
  }
```

At the end of this, you can see `*** goop` on the terminal.

Is there anything that I'm doing here that can be simplified?

For example, the way that I'm creating the `FieldDescription.Latent` seems crazy.  Is there a shorter way that I'm missing?